# reconstruct a sequence from a set of partial orders

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I have a set of elements pairs. Each one of theses pairs means : *In the final sequence the first elements precedes the second element*. 
The set of pairs contains enough pairs to reconstruct a unique sequence.

eg. :

If my set of pairs is `{(A, B), (A, C), (C, B)}`

= *A precedes B*, *A precedes C* and *C precedes B*.

my final sequence is `ACB`.

Now, I need an algorithm to reconstruct sequences from this kind of pair sets.
Efficiency is critical. Any smart tip is welcome !

Comment: And this is homework for which class?

Comment: @Henk, this is a problem for a real application.

Comment: just probing. When you generalize too much it can start to look like an exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a directed graph from those pairs, then perform [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort).

Comment: Here's a reference to the algorithm summary, with pointers to a bunch of implementations:  http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/topological-sorting.shtml

Answer (score 1):

This is problem of Topological sorting of Oriented graph. [Read More](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)